# Trouble finding a path to a node in a BinarySearchTree

Tags: java, path, nodes, binary-search-tree

I need to find the path to a certain node, where a 0 indicates a left branch was taken and a 1 a right.

Here is my code.

```
private static String getPathTo(final BinaryNodeInterface<Character> root, char c)
{
    // TO DO
    String path = "";
    return getPT(root, c, path);
}

private static String getPT(BinaryNodeInterface<Character> root, char c, String path)
{

    if( root.getData().equals(c) )
        return path;
    if( (root.getData() > c) && (root.getLeftChild() != null) )
    {
        path = path + "0";
        getPT(root.getLeftChild(), c, path);
    }
    if( (root.getData() < c) && (root.getRightChild()!= null) )
    {
        path = path + "1";
        getPT(root.getRightChild(), c, path);
    }

    return "CHARACTER NOT FOUND";
}
```

Where it just returns "CHARACTER NOT FOUND" except for the root. I am really confused because it seems so straight-forward, but clearly I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this check wins all the time

```
if( root.getData().equals(c) )
```

You will return `"CHARACTER NOT FOUND"` because the other `if()` statements fall through and return nothing.